# I am facing a error when I compile the source code, It is throwing an error that is given below

Tags: java, package

### java

```
import myPack.*;
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            Factorial f= new Factorial();
            int d = f.fact(a);
            System.out.println("Factorial of " +a+ " is : " +d);
        }
}
```

### Factorial.java

```
package myPack;

public class Factorial
{
        public int fact(int b)
    {
        int c=1;
        for(int i=b;i>0;i--)
        {
        c=c*i;
        }
        return c;
    }

}
```

---

```
E:\Packages>javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:7: error: cannot access Factorial
                        Factorial f= new Factorial();
                        ^
  bad source file: .\Factorial.java
    file does not contain class Factorial
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sou
rcepath.
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the file `Factorial.java` inside a folder called `myPack`.

Then launch javac using : `javac HelloWorld.java`

In java, the file structure has to follow packages. See this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm) for more information.